# inner join not giving results as expected

Tags: mysql

`Product_table`

[image]

`Product_table_link`

[image]

[image]

This be the `product_table` data that is stored inside the database.

[image]

This is the `product_table_link` data that is present inside the DB.I was trying to join these two tables where the `product code=something`.For instance let us take `xyz` as the product.

I was hoping to get the combined results of the two without any nulls present.

I tried :

```
SELECT s1.* FROM (SELECT p1.* FROM product_table p1 INNER JOIN product_table_link p2 
ON p1.product_code=p2.product_code ) s1 WHERE product_code="xyz"
```

But the result is not the combination of the both tables rather it shows me the `product_table`.

```
CREATE TABLE `product_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_name` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `product_code` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `product_description` text,
  `product_type` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `product_image_path` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `product_company_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `product_company_id` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `product_landing_page` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `product_shape` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_flavour` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `product_veg_mark` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique` (`product_code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `product_table_link` (
  `product_code` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `product_weight` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `product_price` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `product_quantity` int(5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_code`,`product_weight`),
  CONSTRAINT `product_table_link_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`product_code`) REFERENCES `product_table` (`product_code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

How do i get the combined results of the two tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your subquery to this

```
SELECT * FROM product_table p1 INNER JOIN product_table_link p2 
ON p1.product_code=p2.product_code
```

You were selecting just from `p1`.

You were doing `select p1.*` which will only select rows from p1. Inner join means you want to select rows from different tables on the basis of some conditions. You need to do `select *` which will select all the rows filtered from the join condition.

Your simplified final query.

```
SELECT s1.* FROM (SELECT p1.*,p2.product_weight,p2.product_price,p2.product_quantity 
FROM product_table p1 INNER JOIN product_table_link p2 
ON p1.product_code=p2.product_code) 
    s1 WHERE s1.product_code="xyz"
```

Comment: Okay , this is working but would you update your answer? like where i was wrong , what part of my query was wrong ?

Comment: @BOTJr. :  Tell me if you need more explanation. Happy to help!

Comment: `SELECT s1.* FROM (SELECT * FROM product_table p1 INNER JOIN product_table_link p2 
ON p1.product_code=p2.product_code ) s1 WHERE product_code="xyz"` i tried this query , what's wrong with one ?

Comment: SELECT s1.* FROM (SELECT * FROM product_table p1 INNER JOIN product_table_link p2 ON p1.product_code=p2.product_code ) s1 WHERE s1.product_code="xyz"

Comment: am i missing any sarcasm here?

Comment: Your simplified query. `SELECT * FROM product_table p1 INNER JOIN product_table_link p2 ON p1.product_code=p2.product_code WHERE p1.product_code="xyz"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125274/discussion-between-botjr-and-fallandlearn).

Comment: This couldnot be the right answer , this query returns two `product_code` columns , there has to be one.

Comment: Didn't get you. two columns ?

Comment: When you will join the two , you will get a `product_code` column from the first table and a `product_code` column from second table.

Comment: Read this. http://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/perform-an-inner-join.php

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p1.* FROM product_table p1 INNER JOIN product_table_link p2 
ON p1.product_code=p2.product_code
```

In the above subquery you are selecting values from p1 only. So, you have to change your query to what FallAndLearn has written.

Comment: it provides me two columns `product_code` , what about that?